# Can't install app from Play Store after installing it using Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, installation, uninstallation

I'm developing an Android app using Android Studio on my Nexus 5 (with latest Lollipop).

Since some time, I can't install the app from the Play Store anymore. If I uninstall the app and then install it from the Play Store, what I get is the app I installed from Android Studio, like it was never uninstalled (but somehow hidden).

Do you know what could be happening?
How can I completely uninstall the app? (maybe removing some files somewhere in the phone?).

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to uninstall it via adb

```
adb uninstall com.your.packagename
```

I already struggled with this bug too. This helped me.

Comment: Thanks! It seems I have to run that command each time I want to go back to the Play Store version. The normal uninstall doesn't work... Do you know if this is a known bug?